# How can I showcase the code snippets in my react app?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a code showcase web app in react. And I wanted to show case the code snippets similar shown below !!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-code-blocks package will do the job pretty well.